# How to change the jquery datatable column color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am creating and populating jquery Datatable dynamically without prior declaring column and rows from the values received from ajax call.Now I want to change my Datatable column header color. Below is the markup of my table.

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-top: 2em;">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 2em;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <table id="adt" class="table table-bordered table-hover compact table-striped" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

How to update the column color in this case? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple css for that like:

```
#adt > thead > tr > th {
    background-color: gray !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Where to add this ? Tried to add in .css file but its not taking from there

Comment: Try to place the css in the page itself inside `<style>` tag and see if that is working first.

Comment: Its Working. One more thing ..How to change the Column Text color ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: in the same css use `color: white !important`. Since background is bit dark, so I think white will look nice as text color. See what works for you better.

Comment: The suggestions about where to place the CSS, and the use of `!important` work, but don't scale well; CSS can get very disorganized very quickly.  You're better off learning CSS specificity rules, and understanding how datatables sets up tables.  Just go into your browser (I use Chrome) and inspect elements.  Then, look at the CSS that's being applied, and you should be able to work out how to specify styles of your own in your own master CSS file.  Furthermore, datatables allows you to specify default styles.  You might research that as well.